# how to convert an image intent into a file type in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-image, android-file

I am developing an app in which i NEED to convert an image into a file. Here's how i tried to implement it:-

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)   
    {
        if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST)
        {
            File camImage= (File) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        }
    }
}
```

There's no error but whenever I take a picture and press ok button it crashes. Is there any way to convert "data" into a file. TIA

Answer (score 0):

The `data` extra is a `Bitmap`. You can call [`compress()` on the `Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream)) to write it to a file (by way of an `OutputStream`). Please do this work on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you:

```
//create a file to write bitmap data
File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "filename");
f.createNewFile();

//Convert bitmap to byte array
Bitmap bitmap = your bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(bitmapdata);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

In Filename you can set path of your to sdcard dir.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)   
        {
            if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST)
            {
                String path= (String) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
                File file = new File(path);
            }
        }
    }
```